# Javascript/xhtml - discovering the total width of content in div with overflow:hidden

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml

I'm writing a javascript based photo gallery with a horizontally scrollable thumbnail bar.

[>> My current work-in-progress is here <<](http://www.sharehost.co.uk/gallerytest/)

I would like the thumbnail bar to stop scrolling when it gets to the last thumbnail. To do this I need to find the total width of the contents of the div - preferably without adding up the widths of all the thumbnail images and margins.

I've put an alert in my window.onload function so I can test the various element dimension functions in different browsers. currently it's showing the value of scrollWidth, which is reported as 1540px by IE and 920px by FireFox, Safari, Opera, etc.

The value 1540 is the correct one for my purposes, Can anyone tell me how to obtain this value in FireFox, etc.

Comment: BTW it returns 1540 in Chrome too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you're just referencing the wrong element.

```
document.getElementById('thumb_window').scrollWidth
```

is giving me 1540 on that page in both IE6 and firefox 2. Is that what you're looking for?

BTW in IE6 the thumbnails extend way past the right scroller.

Comment: I'm testing with FF 3.05 - it returns 920. Not tested with IE6 yet - thanks for the heads up - works fine in IE7.

Comment: Oh great. FF2 reports 1540, FF3 920??

Comment: sorry miss-read your post. scroll width on thumb_window is what I need.

Comment: IE6 problem is related to "hasLayout", fixed by adding "zoom:1" to  style rule for thumb_window.

Comment: Correction: ie6 problem caused my setting the thumb_window size using CSS left and right properties instead of left and width.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for "offsetWidth".
For a cross-browser experience its either scroll[Width/Height] or offset[Width/Height], whichever is greater.

```
var elemWidth = (elem.offsetWidth > elem.scrollWidth) ? elem.offsetWidth : elem.scrollWidth;
var elemHeight = (elem.offsetHeight > elem.scrollHeight) ? elem.offsetHeight : elem.scrollHeight;
```

Comment: In firefox 2 both scrollWidth and offsetWidth are 920 for the element he's alert()ing ("thumb_slide").

Comment: and in IE7 they both return 1540

Comment: document.getElementById('thumb_window').scrollWidth returns 1540 in both IE6 and firefox 2. What does your IE7 say?

Comment: huray! IE7 reports 1540 for thumb_windows scroll width. Thanks!

I'll post a reply to my own question in a moment. with results for Opera and Safari as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the images on server-side and add up their width. (In php you can use the [`getImagesize()`](https://www.php.net/getimagesize) function to do this). Then you can have the total width of all the image passed on to javascript. E.g:

```
$total_width=0;
foreach ($images as $image)
{
   $info=getimagesize($image['file_path'];
   $total_width=$total_width +  $info[0];
}
```

In the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var total_width=<?=$total_width;?>;
</script>
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but the question specifically asks to avoid summing the widths of all the images.

Comment: Sorry, i must've missed that.

Answer (score -1):

What you should do is find the last image element in the div, get its X position relative to its container, add its width, and perhaps add its horizontal margins if it has any.

Pseudo-code:

```
total_width = (last_image.x - container.x) + last_image.width + last_image.left_margin + last_image.right_margin
```

This would be fairly easy to accomplish using [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) since it specifically has built in functionality for getting .last(), getting relative positioning, and fetching margin widths.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a little table:-

```
             thumb_window             thumb_slide
             scrollWidth offsetWidth  scrollWidth offsetWidth
IE7          1540        920          1540        1540
FF 3.05      1540        920          920         920
Opera 9.5    1540        920          920         920
Safari 3.2   1540        920          1540        920
Chrome 1.0   1540        920          1540        920
```